# What does an irrelevant question evaluate to in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

Let's say I have a form with a calculation condition that references another question in the form. For example:

`if (#form/question_1, 'yes', 'no')`

What does this evaluate to in the case that `question_1` is hidden entirely via a display condition? I assume this would be `false` and not, e.g. a reference error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If question_1 is irrelevant, but the question exists in the form, references to the question will evaluate to an empty value (ie: `''`) and should not cause errors.

References to the element's node in XML will return an empty set. IE: `count(#form/question_1)` will return `0`.